# How to make black bar on top of activity animation transparent

Tags: android

Using `overridePendingTransition()` method, a new activity slides up over the old activity. However, there is a black bar that slides underneath the notifications bar. How can I make the black bar transparent so it doesn't show in the animation.

I tried this but it just make the entire activity transparent, and black bar just turns gray.

```
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable( Color.TRANSPARENT );
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable( colorDrawable );
```

Here is a visual illustration.

[image]

Comment: So you used fullScreen mode?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I've edited my question a bit.

Comment: try with this color getResources().getColor(R.color.Transparent)

Comment: What does that mean? Are you trying to call a method? It is not syntactically sound.